# How do I get my modal to pop up only after validation in form occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

After HTML5 validation occurs and the user clicks submit, I am trying to get a modal to pop up thanking the user for submitting the form. The problem is that I am not sure how to give a true or false conditional for the 'required' attribute so that my code can run only after all the fields have been properly filled out. The closest I got is with the following code:

> JavaScript

```
 if(document.getElementById('e-mailClient').required = true || (document.getElementById('comments').required = true)) {

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".open").click(function(){
          $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('slow');
      });

      $(".close").click(function(){
         $(".pop-outer").fadeOut('slow');

      });

    });
    }
```

> HTML

```
 <form name="frm"  method="post" action="serverSide.php" id="my-form">

<input id="e-mailClient" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="on" name="email" required>

 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Submit your comments" rows="10" cols="70" required></textarea>

   <button type="submit" value="submit" id="LeadSubmit" class="open">Send</button>

</form>
```

If someone knows an easier way to have a modal pop-up when clicking submit, and it is only after validation on the front-end has occurred and all form fields are filled out properly, that would be great to know.

Comment: Are these inputs wrapped in a `<form>` tag?

Comment: Yeah all of them are.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the whole form is valid using the HTML5 method `checkValidity()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){

        var form = $('#my-form');
        if (form[0].checkValidity()) {
            $(".pop-outer").fadeIn('slow');
        }

    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
       $(".pop-outer").fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[HTML5 Forms checkValidity()](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity)

Comment: It says: "Uncaught TypeError: form.checkValidity is not a function"

Comment: Oops... Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the form [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) event to show your modal. This event won't be fired unless the form is valid:

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
  <input id="email" type="email" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(() => $('#my-form').submit(event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Form is valid!');
}));
```

Check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgueon5g/1/).

Comment: I got this to work using the submit event, but now after validation occurs, the user has to click twice on the submit button for the modal to appear. Can you please look at my code really quick and tell me once the submit event is fired, how the modal can appear after only one click of the submit button?

Comment: @QuestForMastery this shouldn't happen. As you can see in my example the "popup" appears after a single click. Post your code to JSFiddle, I will have a look then.